# How to not load the theme css when creating a TinyMCE plugin?

Tags: tinymce

I'm in the process of creating my first TinyMCE plugin. I'm including 'tiny_mce_popup.js' in the html and it's loading 'advanced/skins/default/dialog.css' by default.

I don't need TinyMCE to load this css and the only solution I have found so far is documented here http://www.mattephraim.com/blog/tag/tinymce/; and as the author suggests, it is not the most elegant solution. Please help if you know the proper way of handling this.

Answer (score 2):

I found the [official documentation](http://wiki.moxiecode.com/index.php/TinyMCE:API/tinymce.WindowManager/open) by digging 1mm into the 'tiny_mce_popup.js' code. Basicly all you gotta do is in init() of editor_plugin.js, add popup_css as an option and set it to false:

```
ed.windowManager.open({
  ...
  file : url + '/dialog.htm',
  width : 640 + parseInt(ed.getLang('attachment_fu.delta_width', 0)),
  height : 485 + parseInt(ed.getLang('attachment_fu.delta_height', 0)),
  popup_css : false,
  ...
})
```

Comment: I should point out that the official documentation added that option quite a while after my blog post. I'm not sure when that option was actually added to the code though.